# How to use recursion to sum up a list of numbers up until a certain index

Tags: python, function, recursion, sum

I have to write a code that makes use of recursion to sum numbers in a list up until the index is equal to a pre-determined integer value. i.e.

```
  list = [1,4,8,9]
    int = 2
    sum = 1 + 4 (index 0 and 1)
```

below is my code so far, but I am struggling with the logic with my first if statement and hence it isn't working. I get the error 'int' object has no attribute 'index' Any help would be greatly appreciated (PS very new to coding - so sorry if my code isn't the best)!

```
# Sum Recursion

def Arecursion(Alist,index):

    if index > 0:       # if the index point in the list matches the integer return the sum
        return Alist[index] + Arecursion(Alist,index-1)
    else:
        return 0

list_test = [1,4,6,7,10]
int_test = 2
print(Arecursion(list_test,int_test))
```

Comment: One thing I highly suggest is to avoid using keywords as variables names. The names `list`, `sum` and `int` are python keywords. Using them as variables names can create confusion and potentially lead to errors.

Comment: The approach to sum an array recursively, is for each recursive call to add one (current) element to the result of the recursion. That is, for the list `x=[1,2,3,4]` and current index `i`, you will add the element `x[i]` to the result of the recursive call `sum_rec(x, i+1)`. You have to detect the terminating condition (based on `i`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it more complex that you need to. You just need a base case — the current index is too big, and the recursion — the value at the current index plus the rest:

```
def sum_rec(l,max_index, i=0):
    if i >= max_index or i >= len(l):          # base case
        return 0
    return l[i] + sum_rec(l, max_index, i+1)   # recursion


sum_rec([1, 2, 3, 4], 0)
# 0
sum_rec([1, 2, 3, 4], 1)
# 1
sum_rec([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
# 3
sum_rec([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
#6
```

Comment: You can avoid using the `max_index` parameter entirety, if you just decrement `index` at each step

Comment: Yeah, @monk that's a nice idea. It would add a little complication around dealing with the possibility of `max_index` being out of range, but not much.

Comment: Glad it helped @Tdog. Refactoring this to use monk's idea would be a worthwhile challenge and not too hard now that you are this far.